# How can I upload my 195MB Apk on Google play store

Tags: android-studio

I'm using Android Studio to make my App, hopefully, it's finished after 8 months, now my final APK size is over 100MB so I can't upload it on the Google play store, I read some document about splitting by bundle and you can upload up to 4GB but I can't figure it out how to do it, could someone please tell me how I can upload my app on google play store, my app size is 195MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as per the official document.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

main- are those files without this your application will not going to run

patch- are those files which are additional, without this, your application can run

expansion-version- a version that you are giving to your apk so that Expansion files of different version will not conflict

If your app needs more than 100MB of memory, you can use expansion files to store additional APK assets. You can store two expansion files per application. Each expansion file can be up to 2GB in size.

APK files have a maximum file size, based on the Android version your APK supports:

100MB - APKs that target Android 2.3 and higher (API level 9-10 and 14+)

50MB - APKs that target Android 2.2 and lower (API level 8 or lower)
Tip: Users must run Play Store version 5.2 or higher to install 100MB APKs.

Expansion files are hosted at no additional cost. When possible, Google Play will download expansion files when apps are installed or updated. In some cases, your app will need to download its expansion files.

If your expansion files are larger than 100MB, users will see a warning dialog suggesting that they use Wi-Fi to download your app. For more detail click here.

Note: The patch expansion file is semantically the same as the main expansion file—you can use each file any way you want. The system does not use the patch expansion file to perform patching for your app. You must perform patching yourself or be able to distinguish between the two files.

JOBB tool to encapsulate and encrypt a set of resource files and subsequent patches for that set.